# how to configure environment for running https server by Node.js

Tags: node.js, https

creating https server needs setup openssl.
but when download openssl, how to configure? 
i installed Perl and Visual Studio according to some blogs, it is prerequisite for setting up openssl. but they provided instruction based on VS2010, my VS is the latest one 2017, can anyone help to provide detail instruction based on VS 2017 and Perl?